# What is the best way to initialize a JavaScript Date to midnight?

Tags: javascript

What is the simplest way to obtain an instance of `new Date()` but set the time at midnight?

Answer (score 1286, accepted):

The [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) method can take optional `minutes`, `seconds` and `ms` arguments, for example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

That will set the time to `00:00:00.000` of *your current timezone*, if you want to work in UTC time, you can use the [`setUTCHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours) method.

Comment: FYI, I'm running this method ( d.setHours(0,0,0,0) ) in a reduce function on 270K rows, and it's over 20 seconds faster than doing d.setHours(0); d.setMinutes(0); d.setSeconds(0); Great answer @CMS!

Comment: This needs to be done in two lines to keep d as a Date object. I recently fixed a bug that did it in one line: var d = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0). However, d was then a number, not a date since setHours returns a number.

Comment: I've just come across this (late to the party I know), also needing a one line solution returning a Date. For anyone looking for this, [@Zon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894048/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-midnight#answer-30100627) works perfectly: `new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))`.

Comment: Quirk: If you enter today's date as a string it will somehow set the date to yesterday... This is how to get today's date with a string input: `new Date(new Date('2021-04-29').setHours(24,0,0,0)).getDate(); // get 29`

Comment: `new Date(new Date(element).setHours(0,0,0,0));` works perfect for me

Answer (score 343):

Just wanted to clarify that the snippet from accepted answer gives the **nearest midnight in the past**:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(0,0,0,0); // last midnight
```

If you want to get the **nearest midnight in future**, use the following code:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(24,0,0,0); // next midnight
```

Comment: What happens if today is 25 hours long (clocks adjust forward for Daylight Saving)?

Comment: This is client side script, midnight is midnight, despite daylight savings.. Also noteworthy mention.. not every place in the world uses DST (daylight savings time)

Comment: @qntm: daylight saving time change is always applied at 2am-4am, so that it will be only one midnight during that day :). But yes, 3am can happen twice during the day (facepalm)

Comment: @chris No, I mean the second snippet. "24 hours after midnight today" is not always the same thing as "midnight tomorrow". In these cases, does the second snippet work?

Comment: @qntm: Date.setHours does not blindly add 24 hours, it's more intelligent. Instead, it returns a timestamp of the moment, when the clock will show 24 next time. Taking into consideration time saving. Try to play in the console yourself.
Interesting, setHours(25) returns the timestamp of the tomorrows 1am

Comment: @Dan Is this inclusive? Say, it is currently exactly midnight, 0 seconds, miliseconds, etc. Will this just keep the same date, or will it set the date object back to the previous day? (If it is exclusive, then checking the hours for this edge case, before setting it would be appropriate).Tried searching for more info online, but couldn't find it, so I thought I'd ask you.

Comment: @GangstaGraham, the first snippet  `setHours(0,0,0,0)`  is inclusive, while the second  `setHours(24,0,0,0)`  is exclusive, setting the date to tomorrow

Answer (score 136):

A one-liner for object configs:

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
```

When creating an element:

```
dateFieldConfig = {
      name: "mydate",
      value: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)),
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that this date is related to your timezone! Check your date with `toISOString()` if it matches your timezone criteria. Safest ist to use `setUTCHours`, if you want to make it compatible with zero UTC offset.

Answer (score 26):

You can probably use

```
new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)
```

if you need the value only once.

Comment: This does not obtain an instance of a Date, as the OP required.

Comment: This is deffinitely best answer, but needs a little edit to return an instance of a Date. new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0));

Answer (score 25):

Just going to add this here because I landed on this page looking for how to do this in [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and others may do too.

[Rationale: the word "moment" already appears elsewhere on this page so search engines direct here, and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is widespread enough to warrant to being covered going on how often it is mentioned in other date-related SO questions]

So, in version 2.0.0 and above:

```
date.startOf('day');
```

For earlier versions:

```
date.sod();
```

Docs:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/

Comment: to get a date object back, use this `moment(DATE_OBJECT).startOf('day').toDate();`

Comment: And what if you're already using moment.js for one of the many good reasons you might...? How about reading the rationale I gave before adding a sarcastic comment?

Answer (score 9):

If calculating with dates summertime will cause often 1 hour more or one hour less than midnight (CEST). This causes 1 day difference when dates return. So the dates have to round to the nearest midnight. So the code will be (thanks to jamisOn):

```
    var d = new Date();
    if(d.getHours() < 12) {
    d.setHours(0,0,0,0); // previous midnight day
    } else {
    d.setHours(24,0,0,0); // next midnight day
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding usefulness to @Dan's example, I had the need to find the next midday or midnight.

```
var d = new Date();
if(d.getHours() < 12) {
   d.setHours(12,0,0,0); // next midnight/midday is midday
} else {
   d.setHours(24,0,0,0); // next midnight/midday is midnight
}
```

This allowed me to set a frequency cap for an event, only allowing it to happen once in the morning and once in the afternoon for any visitor to my site. The date captured was used to set the expiration of the cookie.

Answer (score 6):

I have made a couple prototypes to handle this for me.

```
// This is a safety check to make sure the prototype is not already defined.
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    if (!this.prototype[name]) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;
        return this;
    }
};

Date.method('endOfDay', function () {
    var date = new Date(this);
    date.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
    return date;
});

Date.method('startOfDay', function () {
    var date = new Date(this);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return date;
});
```

if you dont want the saftey check, then you can just use

```
Date.prototype.startOfDay = function(){
  /*Method body here*/
};
```

Example usage:

```
var date = new Date($.now()); // $.now() requires jQuery
console.log('startOfDay: ' + date.startOfDay());
console.log('endOfDay: ' + date.endOfDay());
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you already have d3.js as a dependency in your project, or don't mind bringing it in, [d3-time](https://github.com/d3/d3-time) ([d3.js library is modular as of v4.0.0](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.0.0)) has got [Intervals](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#intervals).

They might prove useful when setting dates to "default" values, e.g. midnight, 0.00 seconds, the first of the month, etc.

```
var d = new Date(); // Wed Aug 02 2017 15:01:07 GMT+0200 (CEST)
d3.timeHour(d) // Wed Aug 02 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
d3.timeMonth(d) // Tue Aug 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Comment: So I've noticed a trend in JavaScript related questions posted on SO: no matter the complexity of the solutions put forward using native JS, any answers addressing the issue with the help of an external library will inevitably at some point in time get downvoted. Realizing this, I took care to post my answer with the quick preface: _In case you already have example.js as a dependency_. And yet still the downvote, anonymous SO user? that hurts, man :'- (

Comment: I fell that this answer should not be down voted especially since the one proposing usage of moment.js has 16 up votes (at the moment of writing this comment). It does solve the problem in a very concise  and not that obvious way.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [dayjs library](https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/start-of), you can use the startOf('day') method.

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const todayAtMidnight= dayjs().startOf('day');

// Get as a native date object
console.log(todayAtMidnight.toDate());
```

To get the start of a particular day you can use the following:

```
const date = dayjs("2023-02-12").startOf('day');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a DateUtil class in my project that I added some functions to it, btw I wanna share with you those which is related to this topic

```
export class DateUtil {

 static getCurrentUTCDate(): Date {
   return new Date(Date.now() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000); // Convert to UTC timezone
 }

 static getUTCStartOfDay(): Date {
   const now = DateUtil.getCurrentUTCDate();
   return new Date(
     Date.UTC(
       now.getUTCFullYear(),
       now.getUTCMonth(),
       now.getUTCDate(),
       0,
       0,
       0,
       0
     )
   );
 }

 static getUTCEndOfDay(): Date {
   const now = DateUtil.getCurrentUTCDate();
   return new Date(
     Date.UTC(
       now.getUTCFullYear(),
       now.getUTCMonth(),
       now.getUTCDate(),
       23,
       59,
       59,
       999
     )
   );
 }
}
```

Usage example

```
    const startOfDayISOString = DateUtil.getUTCStartOfDay().toISOString(); // 2023-04-24T00:00:00.000Z
    const endOfDayISOString = DateUtil.getUTCEndOfDay().toISOString(); // 2023-04-24T23:59:59.999Z
```