# Javascript how to parse year String to date with zero time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I want to parse `'2015'` string to `Date`

Problem is that adjusts one hour because of winter time and timezone.
Is it possible to get:

`Fri Jan 01 2010 00:00:00` when I do `new Date("2010")` or `moment("2010")`

in case of:

`Fri Jan 01 2010 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)`

I want always hours to be `00:00`.

**EDIT**

Not mentioned: in my case I do not know in which format I get string of date.  It can be `year`, `year month`, `year month day hours` etc. What I am asking is how to format string to date, that all unknown values would be: `01 for days and months`, `00 for hours and  minutes`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to initialize a JavaScript Date to midnight?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894048/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-midnight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `moment` you can have:

```
moment("2015", "YYYY");
// 2015-01-01T00:00:00+01:00
```

if you need to work with your local time, while if you want to use [utc](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), you can have:

```
moment.utc("2015", "YYYY");
// 2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

**EDIT** after your comment:

You can use [moment parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) using an array of formats:

```
var s = "2015";
moment(s, ["YYYY", "YYYY MMMM"]);     // 2015-01-01T00:00:00+01:00
moment.utc(s, ["YYYY", "YYYY MMMM"]); // 2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
s = "2010 February";
moment(s, ["YYYY", "YYYY MMMM"]);     // 2010-02-01T00:00:00+01:00
moment.utc(s, ["YYYY", "YYYY MMMM"]); // 2010-02-01T00:00:00+00:00
```

**EDIT #2**
With `moment` you can use:

```
moment(s, ["YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss", "YYYY MMMM DD HH:mm:ss"]);
```

For example:

```
function testMoment(s){
  var d = moment(s, ["YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss", "YYYY MMMM DD HH:mm:ss"]);
  console.log( d.format() );
}

testMoment("2010");             // 2010-01-01T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 02");          // 2010-02-01T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 Feb");         // 2010-02-01T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 February");    // 2010-02-01T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 02 03");       // 2010-02-02T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 Feb 03");      // 2010-02-03T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 Feb 3");       // 2010-02-03T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 February 03"); // 2010-02-03T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 February 3");  // 2010-02-03T00:00:00+01:00
testMoment("2010 02 03 04");    // 2010-02-03T04:00:00+01:00
// etc...
```

Comment: problem is that I do not know exact format, what I get, for example I can get, `"2010 February"`

Comment: @Edgar I have updated my answer in order to manage multiple formats.

Comment: I use it in quite generic component, once it can receive string like `"2004"` then `"2001 01 02"` etc. I get only string with date, without format type.

Comment: Do you have a finite set of possible input formats? I understand that you can receive different format, but this can cause you issue: how `2001 01 02` should be interpreted? It could be both `1st February 2001` and `2nd January 2001` :(

Comment: it always comes like: `year month day hour minutes ...`, Just not always full data

Comment: @Edgar I have updated again my answer trying to manage inputs that you described

Answer (score 2):

You can set this information in [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor like this:

```
new Date(2010, 0); // params: year, month
```

Or if you need to create date from string:

```
var year = "2010";
new Date(parseInt(year), 0);
new Date(year + "-01-01");
```

Comment: not sure what it does exactly `new Date(year + "/1");` but it works. Thank you

Comment: @Edgar—it "works" purely by chance. It creates a string like "2010/1", which is not a [*format supported by ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) so implementations may fall back to any parsing algorithm they like, including treating it as an invalid string and returning an invalid date.

Comment: @madox2 problem with new changes is that it will support `"2010 02"` string.date . Main problem is that I not sure in what format I will receive string.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper for this.

Note: when you do `new Date()`, you will get `time` as well, but when done like `new Date(yyyy,mm,dd)`, no time is added and time is always `00:00:00`

```js
function createYearStartDate(year){
  return new Date(year, 0,1);
}

(function(){
  var d1 = createYearStartDate("2010")
  console.log(d1)
})()
```