# Create a Date object with zero time in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I'm trying to create a Date in NodeJS with zero time i.e. something like `2016-08-23T00:00:00.000Z`. I tried the following code:

```
var dateOnly = new Date(2016, 7, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(dateOnly);
```

While I expected the output to be as mentioned above, I got this:

```
2016-08-22T18:30:00.000Z
```

How do I create a Date object like I wanted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key thing about JavaScript's `Date` type is that it gives you two different views of the same information: One in local time, and the other in UTC (loosely, GMT).

What's going on in your code is that `new Date` interprets its arguments as *local time* (in your timezone), but then the console displayed it in UTC (the `Z` suffix tells us that). Your timezone is apparently GMT+05:30, which is why the UTC version is five and a half hours earlier than the date/time you specified to `new Date`.

If you'd output that date as a string in your local timezone (e.g., from `toString`, or using `getHours` and such), you would have gotten all zeros for hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. It's the same information (the date is the same point in time), just two different views of it.

So the key thing is to make sure you stick with just the one view of the date, both on input and output. So you can either:

1. Create it like you did and output it using the local timezone functions (`toString`, `getHours`, etc.), or
2. Created it via `Date.UTC` so it interprets your arguments in UTC, and then use UTC/GMT methods when displaying it such as `toISOString`, `getUTCHours`, etc.:

   ```
   var dateOnlyInUTC = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 7, 23));
   console.log(dateOnlyInUTC.toISOString()); // "2016-08-23T00:00:00.000Z"
   ```

---

Side note: The hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds arguments of both `new Date` and `Date.UTC` default to 0, you don't need to specify them if you want zeroes there.

Comment: Wow thanks! I am new to JS and Node and this was really bugging me especially since I couldn't find it anywhere else in StackOverflow.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can Help:

```
let startDate = new Date();
let correctedStartDate = new Date(Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate()));
```

Source:

> 2024-02-09T17:25:29.000Z

Result :

> 2024-02-09T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: Just a copy of the accepted answer but with another twist

Answer (score -3):

You could always just initialize the Date object with your desired date, then use the Date objects `.setHours()` method to set it to midnight.

See also:
[What is the best way to initialize a JavaScript Date to midnight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894048/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-midnight)

Comment: The code the OP showed is the equivalent of calling `setHours(0)` (and `setMinutes(0)` and so on).

Comment: Fair, but if it isn't working, this is another means to do it.

Comment: The point is that doing the above would have exactly the same result.