# JavaScript set future date as today

Tags: javascript

I have the below script in our website which generates a countdown timer. The dateFuture is set to todays date at midnight. Is it possible to set this as the current date so that we don't have to change this every day?

Thank you.

```js
var today = new Date();
dateFuture = new Date(2016, 11, 16, 23, 59, 59);

function GetCount() {

  dateNow = new Date();
  amount = dateFuture.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
  delete dateNow;
  if(amount < 0) {
    document.getElementById("countbox").innerHTML = "Now!";
  } else {
    days = 0;
    hours = 0;
    mins = 0;
    secs = 0;
    out = "";

    amount = Math.floor(amount / 1000);

    days=Math.floor(amount / 86400);
    amount = amount % 86400;

    hours = Math.floor(amount / 3600);
    amount = amount % 3600;

    mins = Math.floor(amount / 60);
    amount = amount % 60;

    secs = Math.floor(amount);

    if(days != 0) {
      out += days + " day" + ((days != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    if(days != 0 || hours != 0) {
      out += hours + " hour" + ((hours != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    if(days != 0 || hours != 0 || mins != 0) {
      out += mins + " minute" + ((mins != 1) ? "s" : "") + ", ";
    }
    out += secs + " seconds";
    document.getElementById("countbox").innerHTML = out;

    setTimeout("GetCount()", 1000);
  }
}

window.onload = function() { GetCount(); }
```

```html
<div id="countbox"></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894048/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the date by using `setHours`, `setMinutes`, `setSeconds` and `setMilliseconds`.

```
var dateFuture = new Date();
dateFuture.setHours(23);
dateFuture.setMinutes(59);
dateFuture.setSeconds(59);
dateFuture.setMilliseconds(999);
```

Comment: shucks I was too late :D