# How to get in .toDate() object beginning of day and end of day?

Tags: javascript

I need to query in my mongoDB in between yesterday beginning of the day and yesterday end of the day which is

T00:00:00 and T11:59:59

However everytime I add .toDate() method to any of the moment/or regular javascript methods it adds 7 hours to the time or something?
and every time i add UTC hours it adds another day which is not correct either.
What can i do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get yesterday date and as said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511323/calculate-the-date-yesterday-in-javascript) you can use:

```
let date = new Date();

date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
```

Then you can set the hour manually with `.setHours()` on date object, below example set the hour to midnight for instance:

```
let date = new Date();

date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

For more information on date Object in javascript you can look the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)

If you combine both you'll have what you're looking for :)

Comment: Does this return a date object ? I need to use it to query for created At field in my mongodb

Comment: `new Date()` returns a Date object, and both `.setDate()`, `.setHours()` modify the object itself. But you can format the date as you want using `.format()` method. I would encourage you to look the docs about Date Object

Comment: It still gives me T07:00 instead of T00:00

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894048/what-is-the-best-way-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-midnight/15790005